# "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'rol_id' cannot be null LARAVEL

Tags: laravel-8

Estoy usando 2 tablas: Roles (id, rol) y Personas (id, nombres, apellidos, rol_id), hice la respectiva relacion de 1 a muchos en cada modelo. Estoy usando el metodo associate() pero creo que esta mal hecha la relacion. Envio los datos desde el postman y al hacerlo tengo el error del titulo

Modelo Rol:

```
class Role extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'rol'];

    public function personas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Persona::class);
    }

}
```

Modelo Persona:

```
class Persona extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'nombres', 'apellidos', 'rol_id'];


    public function rol()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
        
    } 
    
}
```

Controller Persona:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $persona = new Persona();

        $rol = new Role();

        // datos que voy a guardar
        $persona->nombres = $request->nombres;

        $persona->apellidos = $request->apellidos;

        $persona->rol_id = auth()->id();

        $persona->rol()->associate($rol);
        
        $persona->save();
    }
```

[image: Asi envio la informacion]

Comment: Debes incluir como estas enviando los datos desde postman tambien para que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: tienes razon, ya adjunte la imagen de como envio los datos

Comment: Deberías agregar un segundo parámetro al declarar la relación, en ambos `return $this->hasMany(Persona::class, 'rol_id');` y `return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');`. Porque por naturalidad tu **foreing key** debería llamarse `role_id` y no `rol_id`

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, de igual manera aùn tengo el error de que el rol_id llega vacio :(